# TesseractOCR with zend framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2, ocr

I want to use [TesseractOCR](https://github.com/thiagoalessio/tesseract-ocr-for-php) in zend framework 2 project, i've installed TesseractOCR and when i call recognize function from an action i get the following errors:

```
file_get_contents(/tmp/1999512125.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in var/www/res-admin/vendor/thiagoalessio/tesseract_ocr/TesseractOCR/TesseractOCR.php on line 235

unlink(/tmp/1999512125.txt): No such file or directory in /var/www/res-admin/vendor/thiagoalessio/tesseract_ocr/TesseractOCR/TesseractOCR.php on line 248
```

I need to read email address from a hosted image like this [one](http://images.ouedkniss.com/photos_annonces/8523261/email.jpg?v=1455903178).

This is the function from where i call TesseractOCR recognize function:

```
public function getTextFromImage($img){
    $tesseract = new TesseractOCR($img);
    return $tesseract->recognize();
}
```

and this is the action:

```
public function emailAction(){
            $request = $this->getRequest(); 
            if ($request->isPost())
            {

                $id = $request->getPost('id');
                $maj = $this->email($id); 
                $data = new JsonModel(array(
                        'success' => true,
                        'maj' => $maj

                ));
                return $data;

            }       
        }
```

where email is:

```
public function email($source){
        $maj = 0;
        if($source=='toutes les sources') $annonces = $this->getAnnonces();
        else $annonces = $this->getAnnoncesBySource($source);
        foreach($annonces as $annonce){
            $annonce['email'] = $this->getTextFromImage($annonce['email_annonceur']);
            $this->updateEmail($annonce);
            $maj +=1;
            }
        return $maj;
    }
```

Comment: Please, show what you have done, share the code with us.

Answer (score 0):

Does not seems to be a zf2 related pb.

Look at your tmp file *.txt if it exists and if rights are well set.

If it does not exist check why in the source method.

If it exists, check your rights.

No more ;).